# Empty line after a tabular environment

Tags: tables, spacing

I would like to have a little table without caption within my text. There should be, however, some space between the preceeding and following lines of text. The following snippet

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
\\
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{r|c|c|}
&A&B\\\hline
C&AC&BC\\\hline
D&AD&DB\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\\\noindent
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

\end{document}
```

does create a blank line above the table, but gives an error below as there is 'no line to end'. What's the right syntax here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `center` environment already adds some vertical space before and after it (while the `\centering` macro does not). If you want additional space, use, e.g., `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, or `\bigskip`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

\medskip

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{r|c|c|}
&A&B\\\hline
C&AC&BC\\\hline
D&AD&DB\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\medskip

\noindent
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

\end{document}
```

As `center`s spacing is based on that of the (internal) `trivlist` environment, you may also use the [enumitem](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to modify `trivlist`. This will save you typing `\medskip` before and after every in-text table, but it will also affect the spacing of other environments that use `trivlist` (e.g., `flushleft`).

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[trivlist]{topsep=\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{r|c|c|}
&A&B\\\hline
C&AC&BC\\\hline
D&AD&DB\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\noindent
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.

\end{document}
```