# Prevent empty line after tabular environment

Tags: tables, spacing, line-breaking

I have a question related to [Empty line after a tabular environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38671/empty-line-after-a-tabular-environment).

I have a document using package `lineno` to enumerate lines. The rendered document enumerates a line exactly after any `tabular` environment. Is there an empty line after the `tabular` environment? If there is one, how can I erase it?

Example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,english,final,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lineno} % Line numbers

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
1st Para: Bablabla...
\begin{table}[htpb]
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
Mass & $m_1$ & 2.18 \\
Length & $l_1$ & 0.335\\
Center of mass (fraction of length) & $f_1$ & 0.39\\
Joint limits (relative angles) & elbow, shoulder & $[-7,100]$, $[0,160]$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:} Parameters.}
\end{flushleft}
\end{table}

2nd Para: blablabla
\end{document}
```

The rendered document shows a 2 after the table. Erasing the new line in the second paragraph does not solve the "problem".

Comment: Can you please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem?

Comment: Adding an empty line _above_ the table between `Bablabla...` and `\begin{table}` should solve it.

Comment: Leave an empty line before `\begin{table}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To remove the empty line**, go without `flushleft` environment and use `\raggedright`.

**To correct the line number placement**:

- **either** put an empty line before `\begin{table}`;
- **or** remove the `[h]` specifier from the table.

Without one of these changes, the paragraph breaking algorithm (and whence the line numbering algorithm) for the first paragraph is run after the table is typeset. And when the table is placed "here", the line number shows below the table, which is incorrect.

**Remark:** Try to avoid `[h]` specifier, it is considered incorrect from the typographical point of view (it usually doesn't look well in the final document).

**Corrected MWE:**

```
\documentclass[10pt,english,final,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lineno} % Line numbers

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
1st Para: Bablabla...

\begin{table}[tpb]
\raggedright
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
\hline
Mass & $m_1$ & 2.18 \\
Length & $l_1$ & 0.335\\
Center of mass (fraction of length) & $f_1$ & 0.39\\
Joint limits (relative angles) & elbow, shoulder & $[-7,100]$, $[0,160]$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\label{tab:} Parameters.}
\end{table}

2nd Para: blablabla
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn't place the `\label` inside the `\caption` in the “corrected MWE” :)

Comment: @cgnieder Why not?  It's not a bad practice.  See [Label in caption](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7/2693).

Comment: @AlanMunn Damn! Learned something new again... ;) Seriously: I didn't know that.

Comment: @cgnieder IMHO it's just a matter of habit, some people do it, some don't. Me personally, I usually put `\caption` as the before-last line of float and `\label` as a last line of float. However, I didn't want to modify what need not to be.

Comment: I always believed it to be bad practice but apparently I was wrong...

Comment: Thank you very much to all. Indeed the problem is solved. Thank you also for the tips!

Comment: I have tried both approaches, which did not help to fix the issue. What if I have to use `[h]`? @yo'